# Using public and resources folder as alias in laravel

Tags: laravel, git, github

I split a laravel project into 2 parts, backend and frontend, I created 2 repos on GitHub.

In the frontend repo, there are only 2 folders, public and resources folder.

So, when I pull the changes on frontend, I would like all files to replace in backend folder too.

```
------   backend folder 

      ---- public folder -> I want to it be an alias
      ---- resources folder -> I want to it be an alias

-----    frontend folder

      ---- public folder
      ---- resources folder
```

When I create an alias of the public and resources folder in frontend, laravel won't work.

If I create a symlink of those frontend folders, laravel works but index.php file doesn't work as it doesn't follow symlinked path

How can I get it working?

Answer (score 0):

To change public folder directory go to root `index.php`

Under the `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';` add below line:

```
// set the public path to this directory
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return __DIR__;
});
```

To change the resource of view folder directory go to `config/view.php`  and change your desire path.

```
'paths' => [
    realpath(base_path('resources/views'))
],
```

Comment: I don't want to change folder paths, I want to use the alias within the laravel directory.